# Ultimate Texas holdem

Tags: learning

When playing ultimate Texas holdem why did I lose I had a pair of 2 and dealer only had a king and a jack but the 5 community cards had 2 pairs. I know there is no three pair hands but should my pair beat the dealers there for I should win?

Answer (score 1):

Your pair got counterfeit. Your best hand is the board, but the dealer's best hand is the two pairs with K kicker.

Answer (score 1):

The two pairs on the board were both higher than 2, so that immediately makes your pair redundant.
Assuming no better hands (flush/ straight/ full house) then it comes down to who has the best “kicker” (in this case the 5th card in your hand after the two higher pairs).

Sounds like his king clinched it. If there had been an ace on the board, you’d both have had the same best 5 cards and it would have been a split pot.